# AssertionError: Unexpected schema version 0: Unexpected schema version 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am just an android beginner, and i have installed the Android Studio(version is 1.0.2), and create a new blank app which follow the official tutorial named 'Building Your First App', i learned into this page 'http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#LinearLayout' , when i open the res/layout/activity_my.xml, an Event Log display:"AssertionError: Unexpected schema version 0: Unexpected schema version 0",and the file can't open..

pleae give some advices!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was filed recently this year. Take a look here [issues android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74944)

Trying updating your IDE and try disabling assertions in the IDE (in the idea.properties file).

Comment: thank for your replay, please tell me how to  "disabling assertions in the IDE (in the idea.properties file).", and jus now, i just disable the Android Surpport Plugin, and can edit the res/layout/activity_my.xml file ,but cause ' Rendering Problems No render target selected, No Android SDK found' when i press the design button.any ideas

Comment: I also have this issue, even after updating Android Studio on the **Dev** channel to **Android Studio 1.1 Preview 2** (released on 22/01). That issue #74944 was supposedly fixed on 18 Aug 2014.

I managed to find the `idea.properties` file in my `/bin` folder of Android Studio, though I didn't find any comments or settings with a name that relates to disabling assertions. Furthermore, the [tech docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) advise _against_ editing this file directly.

Also, disabling assertions would likely lead to further problems without solving the root cause.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was due to a corrupted `devices.xml` file.
I *erased* (renamed) it and it solved the problem.

On Windows7, that file was located at:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\.android/devices.xml`

I found the info in this post:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=124715

Comment: It's better to post the solution in SO and add the link as reference. The link may be removed.